# Authenticate function not waiting for promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm making an authenticate function. It actually works with hardcoded users, but when I start getting users from Firebase, things start getting asynchronous and issues with timing start happening.

I've got a kind of long-winded Javascript function here that I *believe* returns a promise.

```
function authenticate({ username, password }) {
    return users.then((querySnapshot) => {
        return querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let user = doc.data();
            if (user.username.toUpperCase() == username.toUpperCase())
                return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(function (result) {
                    console.log(password);
                    console.log(user.password);
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result) {
                        const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user.id }, config.secret);
                        const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
                        return {
                            ...userWithoutPassword,
                            token
                        };
                    }
                })
        })
    })
}
```

Console logging seems to confirm that this is a promise. I'll be honest, I copy-pasted a lot of the code inside, so I'm still not entirely sure how it works, but the promise syntax is at least something I'm confident in. After I go through a list of users pulled from Firebase and check that both username and password match, the guts of `if (result)` should run. `result` does come back as `true`, which is correct for what I'm trying to log in with, but my password form rejects me because it continues processing before the authenticate method is finished.

In another Javascript file, I have the method that calls this one.

```
function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    userService.authenticate(req.body)
        .then(user => console.log(user))
        //.then(user => user ? res.json(user) : res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username or password is incorrect' }))
        .catch(err => next(err));
}
```

I'm learning a lot about asynchronous programming recently but this is defying my expectations a bit. Surely doing `.then()` on `authenticate()` should run `authenticate()`, get a promise, even if it's unresolved, then wait for it to resolve before executing the rest of the statements? The current issue is that the method goes ahead, finds no value for `user`, then throws a 400, which I *think* is an issue with asynchronicity. Can anyone explain why the outer authenticate function isn't waiting and how I could make it do that?

Comment: I don't think `forEach` returns anything.

Comment: Btw, I'm pretty certain you should not be getting *all* users from firebase, you should only query for that specific user with the given name.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues:

## Result of forEach

The forEach function returns undefined, see [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). If you need the result of the iteration, you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

## Waiting for the Promise

The following statement sounds like the code does not await the result properly:

> my password form rejects me because it continues processing before the authenticate method is finished.

If you have a javascript promise, you can use the `await` keyword in order to continue the function execution only if the promise is either resolved or rejected. Have a look at the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

In your example, the authenticate function would look like this:

```
async function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  await userService.authenticate(req.body)
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
}
```

Note the `async` and `await` keywords. That way it only returns after the `userService.authenticate(..)` call is fully processed.

Comment: This is not the issue, the OP already has a `.then` there. The issue is the `forEach`.

Comment: You're right. I refined the answer to include the foreach issue and explained why I think the rest of the answer might still be relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) has a `docs` property of type `Array<QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>>`. You can use that and the [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the user. You should also `await` for `bcrypt.compare` while you search for user.

```js
function authenticate({ username, password }) {
    return users.then(async (querySnapshot) => {
        const { usersDocs: docs } = querySnapshot;
        const userDoc = usersDocs.find(doc => {
          return doc.data().username === username;
        });

        if (userDoc) {
            let user = doc.data();
            const pwdCompareResult = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

            console.log(password);
            console.log(user.password);
            console.log(pwdCompareResult );

            if (pwdCompareResult ) {
                const token = jwt.sign({ sub: user.id }, config.secret);
                const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
                return {
                    ...userWithoutPassword,
                    token
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

### Please consider using Firebase Authentication instead

Your auth implementation is not reliable and it transfers sensitive data to every users device, like `usersname` and `password` hashes. Firebase has a very solid authentication system that you should be using.

Comment: You can only use `await` inside an `async function`. Using `then` on `bcrypt.compare` is totally fine. Whichever style for promises you chose, you should not mix it with the other for stylistic reasons though.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the feedback. I do have an `async` to the function, maybe you saw it before I edit it. The scope of `bcrypt.compare` is inside `async (querySnapshot) => {`. I agree, that's just syntactic sugar for promises but it doesn't really matter, we can convert `users.then(async (querySnapshot)` to `const users = await users();`.

Comment: Yes, I mean that you *should* convert that if you already converted the `bcrypt.compare` promise.